# Is there a mistake in my logic when finding the number of odd primes for a given number?

Tags: python, primes

I am making a function that takes in a positive integer and spits out the total number of primes that exist up to the inputted number.
As the title states, I think there is an issue when finding the number of odd primes. However I cannot seem to find anything after 4 days of working on it.

Here are some examples of expected outputs:

- odd_primes(9) = 3
- odd_primes(25) = 9
- odd_primes(40) = 11

I have constructed a nested for loop that checks each odd number in my odd numbers list against every odd number to see if an odd number is prime.
The way I do this is by checking if a number is not prime and if this is true I remove it from my list.
The code seems to be giving some strange results, like 35 and 27 don't get removed. Also, after testing different input values, I have found that the function works as expected for values up to and including 27.
The code is shown below.

```
def odd_primes(num):
    
    Odd_Primes = []
    Odd_numbers = []
    
    #list from 3 till num,can do this as 0,1 not prime
    All_numbers = range(3, num)
    
    #Finding all odd numbers from 3 till num
    for index,number in enumerate(All_numbers):
        # Using that all even numbers except for 2 are not prime 
        if All_numbers[index] % 2 == 1: 
            Odd_numbers.append(number)
     
    #Doing this so won't be removing elements from the Odd_numbers when I am iterating through it
    Odd_Primes = Odd_numbers   
   
    #Finding modulo of all odd numbers with themselves
    for oddindex1,oddnumber1 in enumerate(Odd_numbers):
        for oddindex2,oddnumber2 in enumerate(Odd_numbers):    
            #Checks if the oddnumber1 is not prime
            if oddnumber1 != oddnumber2 and oddnumber1 % oddnumber2 == 0:
                Odd_Primes.remove(oddnumber1)
                break

    
    return Odd_Primes
```

The outputs for the examples stated earlier are:

odd_primes(9):

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

odd_primes(25),

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

odd_primes(40):

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 27, 29, 31, 35, 37]
```

The first two function calls work as expected, the third one does not.

Comment: *"Doing this so won't be removing elements from the Odd_numbers when I am iterating through it"* - What makes you think that?

Comment: The wrong entry is obviously number 35 (is not a prime). Check that your `Odd_numbers` list indeed contains the 5.

Comment: @KellyBundy The reason I thought that this was because initially when I was made the function I didn't have the list Odd_Primes and was getting the same issue I am still getting. So my first assumption was that maybe when iterating through odd_numbers, removing oddnumber1 from the first for loop list also removed it from the second for loop list.

Comment: @PMF I state that 35 is wrong in the question and after checking, Odd_numbers does contain 5.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code completely, but I believe your error comes about because of your assumption that `Odd_Primes = Odd_numbers`  will prevent removing elements from Odd_numbers when iterating through it.  The fallacy is that all you have done is create a second reference to the Odd_Primes list and anything you do to Odd_Primes is also done to Odd_numbers and vice versa.

Here is the way I would do what you are trying to do:

```
def find_oddPrimes(nmb: int)-> list[int]:
    """
      Create a list of all odd primes <= nmb
      Employs the Sieve of Eratosthenes style technique to identify primes this method
      works as follows:
          1.  Create odd_set containing odd integers {3,5,7, .... nmb}.
          2.  Create a prime_set containing the first prime number 2
          3.  Select the lowest number (n) in odd_set and add it to the Prime Set.
          4.  Remove all multiples of n from the odd_set.
          5.  Repeat steps 3 and 4 until n**2  >=  nmb  
          6.  add all remaining numbers in odd_set to the prime set
          7.  create asorted list from prime set
          8.  return all enrtries except for the 2 which is first entry in list

    """
    odd_set = set()
    #  Start with 2 as a known prime
    prime_set = set([2])
    #  Create list of odd numbers starting with 3
    for n in range(3, nmb, 2):
        odd_set.add(n)

    while min(odd_set)**2 <= nmb:
        pn = min(odd_set)
        remove_set = set()
        prime_set.add(pn)
        for n in odd_set:
            if n%pn == 0:
                remove_set.add(n)
        odd_set.difference_update(remove_set) 
    prime_set.update(odd_set)
    return sorted(list(prime_set))[1:]   #skip the 2 since it is the only even prime
```

Of course if all you want is the count of Odd Primes you can replace the return statement above with
`return len(sorted(list(p_set))[1:])`

Comment: This isn't really the Sieve of Eratosthenes but trial division.

Comment: With regard to your comment about trial by division, I disagree. The Sieve of Eratosthenes finds prime numbers up to a limit by iteratively marking non-primes the multiples of each prime, starting with the first prime number.  Multiples of a given prime are then generated as a sequence of numbers.   The key distinction from using trial division is the sequential tests for a candidate number by divisibility by each prime. and once all the multiples are removed, the remaining unmarked numbers are taken as primes.  This in essence is what my solution does.

Comment: Yes, going through the multiples of each prime is what the SoE does. And you don't do that. You do trial division, with your `n%pn == 0`. Doesn't really matter in what order you do the trial divisions. It's still trial division, not going through multiples like SoE does, which is the key distinction.

Comment: @KellyBundy, Yes I agree your concern related to my code and explanation, so I have updated my answer to reflect most of your concerns.  However, I still contend my solution employs a SoE style technique, while not following it to the letter of the law.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. For example when you find the prime 5, you try it as divisor of 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, etc. While an actual SoE would instead go through 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, etc. Which is very different and much more efficient (especially when you reach larger primes). I mean, ok, "style technique" is so vague that I guess one can say that, but it really *is* trial division, so I still find it misleading to mention SoE.

Comment: @itprorh66 , from what I am getting your code checks if any odd number is fully divided by any prime number and if that's the case the odd number cannot be prime? Then it adds the odd number to the remove_set, which is used to remove all non-prime numbers.

Comment: @vishalDhanda yes exactly.  The code selects the lowest value in odd_set as pn upto the sqrt(nmb), then performs pn%n for all n in odd_set.  If pn%n == 0  for any n it is removed from odd_set.  Any number in odd_set > sqrt(nmb) is then added to prime_set.

Comment: [shortened version](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBDoIwEEX3nGI2Jq2BBHBjSOQM7gkxkLbaKENTysKzuGGjd_Iirp0WxcS_an7_f-3M7WGu7tTjNN1Hp5Lt8yWkAqVRHHoh9lZ3cmDYtQVodDwp4aIHV9G5LiIgUWiAXXCZbfAo2SYGyseQcx4SqregYzAEAIljJ23jJPO9GDI-U7y0ArNe51D6-s_2aq1szovjq5Uuanq2woBHz15sAiGswNShYaUb7XwbRcbSz9nfdFmacj5P_1nCdxlv)

Answer (score -2):

Check this code:

```py
def get_primes(n):
    def is_prime(num):
        if num < 2 or num % 2 == 0:
            return False
        for current in range(3, int(num**0.5) + 1, 2):
            if num % current == 0:
                return False
        return True

    return [num for num in range(3, n, 2) if is_prime(num)]


print(get_primes(50))
```

Comment: This is just another prime number finder, it's not an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @911 I understand how your code works, and it looks a lot better than my code hahaha. But it doesn't help answer my question, why my code isn't working as expected.